# Corresponding concept to an ORM in the MERN stack?

Tags: orm, mern

I have used Object-Relational Mapping with SQL Server, such as Entity Framework and NHibernate.

Since Mongo DB (used in the MERN stack) is not relational, and does not require a schema (although it has the capability of a schema), is there a corresponding concept to an ORM in MERN?

Do well designed MERN stacks typically have a Data Access Layer (DAL) written in all in Node-JS?

I'm guessing that since MongoDB doesn't have stored procedures, that the type of work typically done in stored procedures could/should be done in a Data Access Layer?